# Is there a way to specify the structure of a document so that google vision (OCR) processes the doc in a specific manor?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-vision

Google vision document text detection does a good job of detecting symbols & words but it groups the text together strictly by lines and paragraph and even then, sometimes text is logically out of place when processing a document with structured text.

I have already looked at the API documentation and cannot find and examples or references for providing hints (other than language) to change how it parses the document. One possible solution may be to pre-process the document and uses google's api to process the document one piece at a time but would prefer to use google's API directly without intermediate steps.

The code I am using was taken directly from google's vision pdf python example and is reproducible using that code without any changes:

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf

---

```
from google.cloud import storage
import re

def async_detect_document(gcs_source_uri, gcs_destination_uri):
    """OCR with PDF/TIFF as source files on GCS"""
    from google.cloud import vision
    mime_type = 'application/pdf'
    batch_size = 2
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

    feature = vision.types.Feature(
        type=vision.enums.Feature.Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION)

    gcs_source = vision.types.GcsSource(uri=gcs_source_uri)
    input_config = vision.types.InputConfig(
        gcs_source=gcs_source, mime_type=mime_type)

    gcs_destination = vision.types.GcsDestination(uri=gcs_destination_uri)
    output_config = vision.types.OutputConfig(
        gcs_destination=gcs_destination, batch_size=batch_size)

    async_request = vision.types.AsyncAnnotateFileRequest(
        features=[feature], input_config=input_config,
        output_config=output_config)

    operation = client.async_batch_annotate_files(
        requests=[async_request])

    print('Waiting for the operation to finish.')
    operation.result(timeout=180)
    storage_client = storage.Client()

    match = re.match(r'gs://([^/]+)/(.+)', gcs_destination_uri)
    bucket_name = match.group(1)
    prefix = match.group(2)

    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)

    # List objects with the given prefix.
    blob_list = list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix=prefix))
    print('Output files:')
    for blob in blob_list:
        print(blob.name)
```

The results need to be grouped differently, logically, looking at the document the address should be grouped together. Here'show one document is structured (top 4 lines):

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Active              |  2415 ST PETER STREET |  $500,000 (LP) 
| R2222222            |    Port Moody Centre  |           (SP) 
| Board: V, Attached  |       Port Moody      |
| House/Single Family |         V3G 2T5       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

[Here's an example document which shows the document structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyqxj.jpg)

After using the sample provided by google and printing out the result along with page, block and paragraph numbers to hopefully show what's happening. We can see that the text at the top of the file is in the wrong place and the information shown above is spread out over multiple paragraphs and begins at block 5 where it should start at block 0:

```
********* Page Number: 0*************
********* Block Number: 0*************
********* Paragraph Number: 0*************
MAIN FLOOR 
BASEMENT 
TOTAL FINISHED AREA 
UNFINISHED" 
TOTAL AREA

[ snip ]

********* Block Number: 5*************
********* Paragraph Number: 10*************
Active 
2415 ST PETER STREET
********* Paragraph Number: 11*************
$500,000 (LP) 
R2222222 
Port Moody
********* Paragraph Number: 12*************
(SP) 
Board: V, Attached
********* Paragraph Number: 13*************
Port Moody Centre 
********* Paragraph Number: 15*************
V3G 2T5 
********* Paragraph Number: 16*************

[ SNIP ]
```

The above output was generated using this:

```
def annotate(_json):
    annotation = _json['responses'][0]['fullTextAnnotation']
    line = 0
    paranum = 0
    blcknum = 0
    pgenum = 0
    for page in annotation['pages']:
        print('********* Page Number: ' + str(pgenum) + '*************')
        pgenum += 1
        for block in page['blocks']:
            print('********* Block Number: ' + str(blcknum) + '*************')
            blcknum += 1
            for paragraph in block['paragraphs']:
                print('********* Paragraph Number: ' + str(paranum) + '*************')
                paranum += 1
                for word in paragraph['words']:
                    for symbol in word['symbols']:
                        print(symbol['text'], end='')
                        try:
                            bType = symbol['property']['detectedBreak']['type']
                            if bType == 'SPACE':
                                print(' ', end='')
                            if bType == 'EOL_SURE_SPACE':
                                print(' ')
                            if bType == 'LINE_BREAK':
                                print('')
                        except KeyError:
                            print('', end='')
                line += 1
```